# In Meteor with Iron router how would I redirect to a thank you URL stored in the database after form submission

Tags: meteor, router, iron

I have a system written in meteor where when someone submits a form it currently just shows a thankyou message in a modal. My client wants to be able to allow for multiple different thank you pages based on a thank you URL field on a clients record.

I am using iron router. I have successfully setup a server side route but I'm unable to even call that.

What I would like is to on form submission update the database then pull the clients thankyou URL and redirect the user to that. Sorry for not code to tweak but I'm just looking for the best way to handle it.

UPDATE:

Client Side

```
Meteor.call(
     "addSendLeads",
     {
          bookingType: bookingType,
          ad_platfrom: ad_platform,
          senderID: email,
          facebookPageID: fbPageID,
          first_name: first_name,
          last_name: last_name,
          event_name: event_name,
          startDate: startDate,
          email: email,
          phone: phone,
          comments: comments,
      },
      (err) => {
           if (err) {
                     console.log(err);
                     swal(
                          "Error",
                          "Sorry, there was an error. Please try again later."
                     );
           } else {
                target.firstName.value = "";
                target.lastName.value = "";
                target.email.value = "";
                target.phone.value = "";
                target.comments.value = "";
                
                Router.go("/thankyou/" + url);
          }
     }
);
```

The Route in server/routes.js

```
Router.route("/thankyou/:url", { where: "server" }).get(function () {
     this.response.writeHead(302, {
          Location: url,
     });
     this.response.end();
});
```

Hope this helps to clarify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submit form method should return your user custom URL, unless you pull that in the initial stage when you open the form.

With a method, you have a callback (pre Node16) or a .then(result => do_something_with_it). Async methods are already usable in Meteor 2.10.

Your call back or your async effect can call your routing:

```
Meteor.callAsync('submitForm', form) // or Meteor.call('name', {object data}, (err, res) => do_something_with_res)
.then(url => Router.go(url)
.catch(methodErrors => console.log(methodErros))
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply but will Router.go() sent to an external url like https://www.google.com? I thought that had to be a Server route. Which I have all that and the server route works if I go to it directly. but if I call it from the client in the return from the Meteor Call it says Route cannot be found. Do I need to have an additional Route on the client side marked as server. The Iron Router docs are the best in the world.

Comment: I got it to work... Your answer was correct... I just had a syntax error. argh!!